# DrawKeypoints function not working on OpenCV3.0/Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, opencv3.0, sift

I've been trying to use the SIFT detector for about a week now and when I finally get it working, I get an error with the `cv2.drawKeypoints()` function. The code is as follows:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('\\home\\gaiarsa\\matrix\\poste.jpg')
gray = cv2.imread('\\home\\gaiarsa\\matrix\\poste.jpg', 1)

sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

dummy = np.zeros((1,1))

kp = sift.detect(gray, None)

img = cv2.drawKeypoints(gray, kp,dummy, flags=cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

cv2.imwrite('sift_keypoints.jpg', img)
```

After I run it I get the error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!outImage.empty()) in drawKeypoints, file /home/gaiarsa/opencv/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp, line 113
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "sift.py", line 14, in <module>
    img = cv2.drawKeypoints(gray, kp,dummy, flags=cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
cv2.error: /home/gaiarsa/opencv/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp:113: error: (-215) !outImage.empty() in function drawKeypoints
```

When I try removing the `dummy` array from the function arguments, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sift.py", line 14, in <module>
    img = cv2.drawKeypoints(gray, kp, flags=cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
TypeError: Required argument 'outImage' (pos 3) not found
```

Comment: Try `cv2.drawKeypoints(gray, kp, img, flags=cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)` (without `img = ` and `dummy`)

Comment: Tried it. It didn't work. Still got the !outImage.empty() error

Comment: Then no clue.. Good luck! ;D

Comment: Sometimes then the source and target image are not the same, some flags don't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was reading a png file as a jpeg. As soon as I changed it, it worked

Answer (score 0):

Just check you filenames. If they are wrong you'll not get nice error messages, but just get NULL pointers or whatever, and the program will only break way up ahead giving a message such as this...

Answer (score 0):

Path doesn't exist!(if the extension is .png is the same)

'\home\gaiarsa\matrix\poste.jpg'

Check the path before use it:

```
import os
if not os.path.exists('path/file'):
    print('Incorrect path or file missing')
    exit(0)
```